# Is there a way to improve the performance of pyspark substract?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-emr

I'm having two DF, each reads 1 TB data. Below code runs very slow. Is there a way to improve it's performance?

```py
diffDF = df1.subtract(df2)
```

Comment: Restructure the question based on the guidelines here to better support you 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48427186/7989581

Comment: Could you share spark submit parameters?

Answer (score 0):

In general, if you have two large datasets that you must shuffle you can't do much to improve the performance (except of configurations tuning).

However, depending on the data and specific use case, you can try the following mitigations:

1. Assuming you have some id column(s) that uniquely define each record in your datasets, instead of `except/subtract` you can use `left anti-join` that might be faster (see [Any difference between left anti join and except in Spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61492900/any-difference-between-left-anti-join-and-except-in-spark)).
2. In some cases if you can eliminate irrelevant records from `df2` before the join and keep a relatively small number of ids to join, you may be able to perform `broadcast` join and that for sure will significantly improve the performance.